# Rails 7 import map with javascript package from cdn throwing CORS error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I'm trying to import a JS package hosted on a CDN using the new Rails 7 import maps feature. However, whenever my Rails project loads I get a `CORS` related error in this form:

```
Access to script at 'https://cdn.vender-application.com/package.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My `importmap.rb` looks something like this:

```
pin "va_cdn", to: "https://cdn.vender-application.com/package.js"
```

I added the `rack-cors` gem along with a `cors.rb` file, however it had no effect. Example cors files:

- I first tried with a general `config/initializers/cors.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end
end
```

- After that failed I tried being more specific as I've heard some services don't like an `*` Origin. I used `http://127.0.0.1:3000` as that was the exact origin listed in the error message. I tried both with `resource '*'` and a more specific one:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
    resource '/', headers: :any, methods: :any
    resource '/index', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end
end
```

I seems like it something specific to importmaps, since
this code will successfully get the package:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://cdn.vender-application.com/package.js" %>
<% end %>
```

I'd prefer to use the new recommended way of getting this package, rather than inlining the call.

Comment: Could you add the details of the error you have? like the stacktrace.